# Navbar doesnt collapse but works fine

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar, min

the min navbar opens fine on click and the link scroll works fine but it doesn't collapse for some reason. Sorry I am a js noob here

JS used is bootstrap-3.

Code:

```html
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" />
<div class="container">
   <nav class="main-menu">
      <div class="navbar-header">
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
      </div>

      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a data-scroll href="#about">About us</a></li>
            <li><a data-scroll href="#service">Services</a></li>
            <li><a data-scroll href="#GetInvolved">Get Involved</a></li>
<li><a data-scroll href="#testimonials">Testimonials</a></li>
            <li><a data-scroll href="#getintouch">Contact</a></li>
<li><a style="color:#F8DC40;background-color: black"  data-scroll href="#service">Request Service</a></li>
<li><a style="color:red;background-color: #F8DC40" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#opendonatemodal" data-scroll href="#">Donate Now</a></li>
</ul>
      </div>
   </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, maybe you check bootstrap migration, it'll be helpful https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/ , and your project very legacy and hard to create your issue. But You can check your question from GitHub Bootstrap: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues .

Comment: Is there any error in the console?

Comment: Bootstrap 3.0.3v require jquery (>= 1.9.0)

Comment: @DeC Could you please check this domain covidhome.help on mobile aspect ratio? might make you understand my concern. Sorry a total noob here

Comment: `collapse in` is responsible for opening the navbar. but when closes bootstrap removes the `in` class. See you can see in the [bootstrap_css_3.0.3][1] . Search for `.collapse.in` and `collapse` above it.


  [1]: https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.css

Answer (score 0):

In your code bootstrap class `in` is not getting removed when clicking on the button. Try to search for what's wrong with your code. If you try to toggle `in` class from the console using the following command. Just run the following command multiple times in console.

```
document.querySelector('#navbar').classList.toggle('in')
```

You can see that it starts to open and close accordingly.

`collapse in` and `collapse` from Bootstrap 3.0.3

```
.collapse {
    display: none;
}
.collapse.in {
    display: block;
}
```

`in` class is responsible to show or hide the HTML element.